# What is 'religious osmosis' in Total War Attila?

Tags: attila-total-war

Some buildings have a new quality, previously unseen in Total War games, called 'religious osmosis' (separate from religious influence).

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here , but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, it's the amount of religious influence exuded to neighboring provinces.

Answer (score 0):

The ability fora majority religion to gain followers despite already being a majority, IE you have 70% relgion of your faction in your province osmosis would increase conversion to your religion

Comment: No, pretty sure this is not it. Religious conversion seems to work like before: in proportion to total points of religious influence, e.g. if you have 2 influence for Germanic Paganism, 1 for Arian Christian and 1 for Manicheism, it will converge towards 50% Paganism, 25% Arian Christian and 25% Manicheism.